# Threads will only sort the first partition of the array (Bubble sort, Pthread)

Tags: c, sorting, unix, pthreads

I am trying to sort an array with length of 1000 using 10 threads. The first thread is 0 to 99 and the second is 100 to 199.... My problem is that only the first 100 elements are sorted and the rest are left untouched even though the threads run as expected in all aspects other than sorting.

```
#define N 1000
int arr[N];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i;

    //Filling the array with random integers
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=1+rand()%200;
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d | ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /*      START OF THREAD SECTION    */

    pthread_t sorters[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&sorters[i],NULL,sortArr,(void*)i);
        pthread_join(sorters[i],NULL);
    }

    /*      END OF THREAD SECTION     */


    return 0;
}
```

thread:

```
void* sortArr(void *num)
{
    int i,j,temp,cast,first=0,last;

    //Casting
    cast=(intptr_t)num;

    //Calculating first and last element
    first=(cast*100);   
    last=first+99;

    printf("first %d , last %d \n",first,last);

    printf("Not sorted:\n");
    for(i=first;i<last;i++)
    {
        printf("%d | ",arr[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");

    /*    SORTING */
    for (i = first; i < last-1; i++)
    {  
        for (j = first; j < last-i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    /*    SORTING */

    printf("Sorted:\n");
    for(i=first;i<last;i++)
    {
        printf("%d | ",arr[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
}
```

With my current knowledge I can only try so many things to figure it out and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of having 10 worker threads when only one worker runs at a time? And you are only sorting blocks of 100 numbers, your are not sorting the whole array.

Comment: @Pablo It seems that soring subranges of 100 items is desired behavior.

Comment: @VTT yes, that may be true, but as the OP has not really specified whether this is the desired behaviour, it's still worth pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner loop exit condition makes it immediately exit if `first` is not 0. It should be

```
for (j = first; j < last + first - i; j++)
```

Also those 10 threads are rather pointless because they don't run in parallel. You should move join into separate loop.

Comment: Thank you, I feel dumb now, Yeah I joined the threads in the same loop so i could see what each thread prints without it being a cluster caused by 10 threads printing in parallel.Thank you again mate.

Comment: @GiorgosDiamantopoulos about the threads: OK, if this was just for testing purposes. Otherwise it didn't make sense.